# How to turn on/off a function on a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working in a mini-game-project (Simons game) that many of you may know. Where the computer plays a random sequence of buttons in which players have to follow to go to the next level in the game e.g: [one click first round, two clicks second round..].

I already did all the button effects as well as make the machine plays buttons randomly in a range of ten rounds. So, what I would like to do is use a button to turn on and off the function that makes the computer clicks By Itself using a button.

I already tried using the jQuery function `$(startButton).on('click', clickByItself);` alone but it did not worked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //four variables representing its button effects 
  //button blue effect
  var blueButtonEffect = code here;

  var greenButtonEffect = code here;

  var redButtonEffect = code here;

  var yellowButtonEffect = code here;

  //to be used on the buttonEffects()/clickByItself()
  var arr = [blueButtonEffect, redButtonEffect, greenButtonEffect, yellowButtonEffect];
  let enabled = true;
  let times = 0;
  //makes button effects play itself randomly 
  function clickByItself() {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    $(arr[random]).click();
    if (++times < 10) {
      setTimeout(function() { clickByItself(times); }, 1000);
    }
  }
  clickByItself();

  function turnOnTurnOff() {
    if (enabled == true) { //TRYING TO TURN ON/OFF THE FUNCTION ON BUTTON CLICK..
      $(startButton).on('click', clickByItself);
    }else{
      $(startButton).on('click', clickByItself);
    }
  }
```

Now, I am trying to use a function `turnOnTurnOff()` to see whether I could do the effect of turning on and off with the click of a the `startButton`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.off()` method of jQuery to remove an event listener as follows.
I added two `div`s for better demonstration.

One button binds and unbinds (toggles) the click handler of the second button using jQuery's `.on()` & `.off()`. When the click handler is bound to the second button, clicking it will update the `div` with a number. When the click handler is unbounded from the second button, clicking the second button will do nothing. Two lines of interest in the JavaScript code below are decorated with a comment each. The rest is for demonstration.

```js
window.enabled = false;
window.count = 1;

// Initialize the view (for demo)
$(function() {
  $('#switchIndicator').html(`<p>${enabled ? 'Switch is ON' : 'Switch is OFF'}</p>`);
  $('#btn').html(enabled ? 'You can click me :-)' : 'You CANNOT click me');
});

// Toggle click functionality using jQuery's .on() & .off() methods
function toggle() {

  enabled = !enabled;

  if (enabled) {
      // Line of interest #1: jQuery .on()
      $('#btn').on('click', handleClick);
  } else {
      // Line of interest #2: jQuery .off()
      $('#btn').off('click', handleClick);    
  }

  $('#switchIndicator').html(`<p>${enabled ? 'Switch is ON' : 'Switch is OFF'}</p>`);
  $('#btn').html(enabled ? 'You can click me :-)' : 'You cannot click me :-((');
  $('#btn').removeClass(enabled ? 'disabled' : 'enabled').addClass(enabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled');
}

function handleClick() {
  $('#counter').append(` ${count++}`);
}
```

```css
/* CSS */
#btn.enabled {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

#btn.disabled {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="switchIndicator"></div>

<button id="switch" onclick="toggle()">On/OFF Switch</button>
<button id="btn"></button>

<div id="counter"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
function clickByItself() {
    if(enabled) {
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
        $(arr[random]).click();
        if (++times < 10) {
            setTimeout(function() { clickByItself(times); }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
clickByItself();

function turnOnTurnOff() {
    if (enabled) {
        enabled = false;
    } else {
        enabled = true;
        clickByItself();
    }
}

$(startButton).click(function() {
    turnOnTurnOff();
});
```

Comment: I don't really understand why you changed `enabled` to a number?

Comment: Yep no problems :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in multiple ways. One is to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` and store it inside a variable. When you need to stop it, just call `clearInterval`.

Comment: Ok, but you mean in the ```clickByItself()``` function?

Comment: Yep, a way to do it is assigning a setInterval in a static variable inside `clickByItself`. The callback given to the interval is the actual content of the function. When you need to turn it on, you call the `setInterval` and when you need to turn it off you just call `clearInterval` on your stored interval.

Comment: Oh and I didn't notice first but you're calling back `clickByItself(times)` but the function doesn't have this parameter :)

Comment: It indeed works, however, when I click it again it doesn't display all the entire random effects again. Only one effect. So, after two clicks on the ```starButton``` it will display again a button effect instead of 10.

Comment: Yes, that's the exact effect! I am trying to fix it here.